# Angular : Show a modal from a component

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog

I have a app.component.ts, which is my main component.
There is his app-routing.module.ts, which by default takes you to a "CalibrationComponent" page.

```
app.component.html

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="auth">Authentification</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="appareils">Appareils</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My calibration.component.html looks like this:

```
<p> Calibration works !</p>
<!-- Modal -->
<ng-template #content >
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <p> Header body</p>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <p> Header footer</p>
    </div>
</ng-template>

<div class="calibrationDiv" *ngIf="startCalibration" >
    <input type="button" class="Calibration" id="Pt1">
    <input type="button" class="Calibration" id="Pt2">
    <input type="button" class="Calibration" id="Pt3">
    <input type="button" class="Calibration" id="Pt4">
    <input type="button" class="Calibration" id="Pt5">
    <input type="button" class="Calibration" id="Pt6">
    <input type="button" class="Calibration" id="Pt7">
    <input type="button" class="Calibration" id="Pt8">
    <input type="button" class="Calibration" id="Pt9">
</div>
```

And my calibration.component.ts looks like this:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calibration',
  templateUrl: './calibration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calibration.component.scss']
})


export class CalibrationComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() startCalibration: boolean = true;
  @ViewChild("content") content: any;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.modalService.open(this.content);
  };
}
```

When I go to my Calibration component (this is the default route), my modal doesn't show up. Do you know why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

I had the nodemodule bootstrap 3.7, which is not compatible with ng-bootstrap. I had to upgrade bootstrap to 4.0 and now everything works.

Thanks.